# How to find quality of a downsample image and which is best algorithm to downscale?

Tags: images, image-quality

We are using an opensource application to process the images, It is using nearest neighbor, bilinear and bicubic algorithms to downsample the images.

In most of the scenarios the image are good, but when it comes to images film grain images, all the three algorithms are failing.

As it is a open source tool, we can edit the source code of the tool. but the problems are , "We don't know which algorithms are best for printable downsampling images" and "How to compare them".

Thanks,
Praveen Ravipati.

Comment: Are "film grain images": "grainy images on film," "images of film grain only" (for use as an overlay," "images that have had a digital film grain effect applied," or "images that have a layer mask (etc) of film grain composited non-destructively"?

Comment: Any images, that are having film grains

Comment: The best filter is a infinitely wide sinc filter. But since you dont have infinite amount of time you need to use a filter that is not best. A lsnczos windowed sinc is quite good. Though you may prefer something else that rings less.

Comment: @joojaa Thanks, I checked sin(Lanczos) is Really good.

Comment: sin and sinc are not the same thing. a Blackman harris filter is also good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GIMP has a "Sinc (Lanczos 3)" interpolation method, which is excellent for downsampling.  However if the original images are large, with lots of small details such as film grain, and you are downsampling much smaller, then there's not really much you can do. Details will be lost when resampling, no matter what you do. It's a fact of reality.

I suppose you could try adding a film grain effect again, after you have downsampled it.

How to compare them?  Look at them side by side at 100% zoom.

Might I ask why you are downsampling the image?  If it's for print, why do that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The application we are using, actually create a new image with multiple images, like photoshop or GIMP. it a JAVA application, it downsample the image for fittest size, before merging it to other images.

Comment: Do you mean like a photo mosaic?

Comment: yes, its like photo mosaic.

Comment: So, you could perhaps add a film grain effect to the finished photo mosaic?

Comment: No, im not adding film grain effect in finishing photo.

Comment: we can able to check image quality by using imagemagick tool.